# XAxis time scale from csv data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Although I have read several posts on this subject , I could apply to my case.The source of my data is in csv format from a url .When i represent them using d3.js in the X axis shows the exact minute . How could represent fractions of time every 30 minutes ?.
Time format csv url data:

```
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2
2015-11-24 10:39:37 UTC,1049233,4,10
2015-11-24 11:09:37 UTC,1049234,0,10
2015-11-24 11:39:36 UTC,1049235,2,12
```

,so:
X Axis: ---10:39-----------11:09-----------11:39----------

My object:

X Axis: ---10:30-----------11:00-----------11:30-----------

This is the code i am using:

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: -30, bottom: 120, left: 40 },
        width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC").parse;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .6);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);



    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format,30)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d)) })

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

,and the csv data:

```
d3.csv("https://website/dat.csv",
        function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = (d.created_at);
            d.value = +d.field1;
            console.log(d.value);
        });

        x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(7," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
          .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.9em")
            .attr("dy", "-.55em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Nº Personas");

        svg.selectAll("bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The final object is to compare two csv url data with different time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that the data would be in hh:3m format, you can just use

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format,30)
        .tickFormat(
            function(d) { 
                var toDisplay = d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
                    toDisplay = toDisplay.substring(0,3) + "0";
                    return toDisplay;
                    })
```

(you get the point, even if the data is in some other format, you can just change it inside the function and return in the desired format)

Comment: Thanks.It works great!!  however i am using another csv url source data with the main object to compare the two csv url data.This second url csv data has an offset of x(6 in this case) minutes respect first so:
(Second csv url data)
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2
2015-11-24 10:39:37 UTC,1049713,4,10
2015-11-24 11:09:37 UTC,1049714,0,10
2015-11-24 11:39:36 UTC,1049715,2,12
,and the X label is displaced from the first csv.

Comment: didn't get you, can you edit the question and include these details or try to explain it better in comments :)

Comment: ok,i will explain better in comments. I have used your solution and modifyng my code works better.
Thank you very much.